# Make a div appear after another is hovered over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a box appear when the user hovers over a separate box. I am having trouble getting it to work.

Here is the html

```
<div class="division_left" id="account">
      <div class="container"></div>
      <span>Account</span>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
#account:hover + .container {
visibility: visible;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

again I am trying to get the `container` to show when `#account` is hovered over. It just is not showing up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `#account` is a parent of `.container` rather than its sibling - you need the 'direct descendant' selector, `>`, rather than the 'adjacent sibling' selector, `+`, i.e.

```
#account:hover > .container {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Instead of

```
#account:hover + .container {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Support for the 'direct descendant' selector is as follows:

> IE 7, IE8, IE9 pr3, FF 3.0, FF 3.5, FF 3.6, FF 4b1, Saf 4.0 Win, Saf
>   5.0 Win, Chrome 4, Chrome 5, Opera 10.10, Opera 10.53 and Opera 10.60

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/KvNfs/)

Comment: what if it was not nested in the `#account` div. What if it was somewhere else? like further down and in another area. I tried using the plus and it still did not work? Does it have to be in the div?

Comment: I tried doing that I placed the `container` in a random place in the html and removed the `>` and it did not appear.

Comment: It turns out you can ONLY can selectors like this on siblings or on children elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/wNdBw/

```
div {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.container` isn't a [*sibling*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) of `#account` its a child so you need to instead use the direct child combinator `>`

`#account:hover > .container`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmjRu/24/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JQuery Hover function instead? Much better and stable than anything else. you can play with effects as well.

HTML :

```
<div class="division_left" id="account">
  <div class="container" style="display:none"></div>
  <span id="showAccount">Account</span>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
$('#showAccount').hover(function(){
   $('.container').toggle('fade');
});
```

This will give you much better effect than regular CSS.

Try it and let me know..

Or I will add JSFiddle if you need.

**Update** :  http://jsfiddle.net/V8QbY/ - Here it is

Regards,

Rahul.